# Java Custom Size String Comparator

Tags: java, compare, comparator, string-comparison

I have the following Strings:

50ml,100g,3.5ml,10g,0.4g,320ml and I need to order them as follows:

0.4g,10g,100g,3.5ml,50ml,320ml

The criteria is order the type of size measure alphabetically (g comes before m) and then the actual size ASCENDANT (0.4 10g 100g)

How can I achieve this using a Comparator?

```
protected int compareInstances(String instance1, String instance2) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Is there only "ml" and "g" or can it be anything?

Comment: It can be any letter. I don't know how can I compare a String by multiple criterias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest (however not the prettiest) approach to take here is to simply split the values into prefix (actual value) and suffix (measurement), to then compare these seperately.

So I implemented a `Comparator<String>`, which splits the given values into prefix and suffix, then firstly compares the suffix alphabetically. (Disclaimer: Uppercase letters will be considered as "smaller" than the lowercase equivalent) If they are equal, the prefix values are compared.

Here is a small example with the described logic:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "50ml,100g,3.5ml,10g,0.4g,320ml,32.3a,3.6ml";
        String[] splitInput = input.split(",");
        System.out.println("Before:\t" + Arrays.toString(splitInput));
        Arrays.sort(splitInput, new MyComparator());
        System.out.println("After:\t" + Arrays.toString(splitInput));
    }

    static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // extract the suffix by removing the digits and dots
            String suffix1 = o1.replaceAll("[\\d\\.]", "");
            String suffix2 = o2.replaceAll("[\\d\\.]", "");
            if (suffix1.compareTo(suffix2) != 0) {
                return suffix1.compareTo(suffix2); // String#compareTo
            }
            // extract the prefix by removing the characters
            double value1 = Double.parseDouble(o1.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", ""));
            double value2 = Double.parseDouble(o2.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", ""));
            // compare the double values
            return (int) Double.compare(value1, value2);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Before: [50ml, 100g, 3.5ml, 10g, 0.4g, 320ml, 32.3a, 3.6ml]
After:  [32.3a, 0.4g, 10g, 100g, 3.5ml, 3.6ml, 50ml, 320ml]
```

Comment: I guess this will show 1L as bigger than 1200ml. So, if the inputs are clean, then this is fine.

Comment: You are right. If the suffix is uppercase, it will be considered as "smaller" when compared to a lowercase suffix by the `String#compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  Instead of a separate comparator, I would write a simple sort method to sort and return the sorted string.  Of course, the return value could be modified to return any data structure.

```
String s = "50ml,100g,3.5ml,10g,0.4g,320ml";
    
String result = sort(s);
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
0.4g,10g,100g,3.5ml,50ml,320ml
```

- This method first splits the string on the comma delimiter.
- Then it streams those strings and first, splits them between the digit and the letter (I believe it is best to do this outside of the comparator to reduce repetitive splitting).
- then the values are sorted, first on unit and then on amount, and rejoined into their original format.

```
public static String sort(String s) {
    String[] amts = s.split(",");
    return Arrays.stream(amts)
            .map(amt -> amt.trim().toLowerCase().split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\p{Lower})"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[1])
                    .thenComparing(
                            arr -> Double.parseDouble(arr[0])))
            .map(arr -> arr[0] + arr[1])
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

- If an array is desired, change the return type to `String[]`
- and change `.collect(Collectors.joining(","));` to `.toArray(String[]::new);`